# Importing schedules using the Rundeck API

Tags: rundeck

Is there a Rundeck API call for loading named schedules that can then be referenced in job definitions?
It can be done from the UI, but I have not found any information about doing it via the API.

Answer (score 0):

On Rundeck Community, you can enable and disable job schedules following [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#enable-scheduling-for-a-job) and [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#disable-scheduling-for-a-job) endpoint. [Here](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/95797/rundeck/7TNfX9k?version=latest#80c81154-dbfa-b8cc-d29c-0a90ee02ee70) and [here](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/95797/rundeck/7TNfX9k?version=latest#2fd37144-c1bf-f3f7-3cae-24b6e4a0ee73) you can see good examples of how to use these endpoints.

But if you mean about [project schedules feature](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/schedules/project-schedules.html#project-schedules-enterprise) it's exclusive of Rundeck Enterprise, and that is covered by the [dedicated support team](https://www.rundeck.com/community-vs-enterprise).

Comment: Thanks @MegaDrive68k!  I'm referring to Job-Independent Schedules.  I'll contact the support team.